# How to trigger a UIViewController segue based on gesture actions in a UItableViewCell using Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am prototyping an iOS app, using Xcode and swift language, that uses different gesture actions in a given UITableViewCell to initiate a particular segue to another UIViewController.

The UI is modeled after the mail app where a pan gesture recognizer is added to a UITableViewCell view. Depending on if the UITableViewCell view is panned left or right or how far it is panned before released should determine which 1 of several view controllers is segued to.

I have successfully set up the pan gesture recognizer in the UITableViewCell to my satisfaction by switching on the translationInView and the action and animations work great.

What I was planning to do on each switch condition is add a performSegueWithIdentifier to trigger 1 of the 4 different segues, but apparently this does not work from within a UITableViewCell.

[link to github files](https://github.com/chieger/flexbuck-1.0)

Any help is GREATLY appreciated! :D
Charlie

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does performSegueWithIdentifier make the app crash, does it do nothing?

Comment: The performSegueWithIdentifier method is not recognized in the file of type UITableViewCell. I am now aware this is because the PerformSegueWithIdentifier is a UIViewController method. I am still unsure, however, about how to coordinate between the UITableViewCell, which is handling all the gesture recognition and the parent UIViewController which is able to perform the segue.

Comment: The Xcode project is uploaded to github [click here](https://github.com/chieger/flexbuck-1.0)

Comment: The project on Github is just an empty template. Make sure you pushed whatever changes you made in local git source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `performSegueWithIdentifier` within a UITableViewCell because it's viewController's method.

So

1. define your custom tableViewCell protocol
2. make your viewController conform to it then
3. when you need perform a segue delegate the need to viewController

Comment: great, this is very helpful. I am unsure, however, how to make the viewController conform to the tableViewCell. The Xcode project is uploaded to github [link](https://github.com/chieger/flexbuck-1.0)

Comment: @Charlie you seems pretty new to cocoa touch so find a book and learn step by step. This kind of question wouldn't help you much